# record audio on iphone with phonegap

Tags: iphone, audio, cordova, record

Does anyone has source code for record audio and playback with Phonegap?I already tried sourceCode from [Phonegap API page](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_media_media.md.html#media.startRecord),but I can't get it works.

Comment: maybe you can post what you already tried so others can try to figure out whats wrong

Comment: Post your code dude and I'll try and help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">


// Called when capture operation is finished
//
function captureSuccess(mediaFiles) {
    var i, len;
    for (i = 0, len = mediaFiles.length; i < len; i += 1) {
        uploadFile(mediaFiles[i]);
    }       
}

// Called if something bad happens.
// 
function captureError(error) {
    var msg = 'An error occurred during capture: ' + error.code;
    navigator.notification.alert(msg, null, 'Uh oh!');
}

// A button will call this function
//
function captureAudio() {
    // Launch device audio recording application, 
    // allowing user to capture up to 2 audio clips
    navigator.device.capture.captureAudio(captureSuccess, captureError, {limit: 2});
}

// Upload files to server
function uploadFile(mediaFile) {
    var ft = new FileTransfer(),
        path = mediaFile.fullPath,
        name = mediaFile.name;

    ft.upload(path,
        "http://my.domain.com/upload.php",
        function(result) {
            console.log('Upload success: ' + result.responseCode);
            console.log(result.bytesSent + ' bytes sent');
        },
        function(error) {
            console.log('Error uploading file ' + path + ': ' + error.code);
        },
        { fileName: name });   
}

</script>
```

with

```
<input type="button" class="button-big" style="width: 100%;" onclick="captureAudio();" value="RECORD AUDIO NOTES">
```

Comment: There is a load of styling in my button there, but try ** onclick="captureAudio();" ** as the function...